# Django select between DB dates

Tags: django

with [_range](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/querysets/#range) you can do a between query

```
start_date = datetime.date(2005, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime.date(2005, 3, 31)
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__range=(start_date, end_date))
```

You can use this if you have 2 dates and want to check if the date in het DB is between those 2 dates

In my case I have 1 date and want to check if that date is between my 2 date fields in db

```
class Deals(models.Model):
    #stuff
    starting = models.DateField()
    ending = models.Datefield()
```

How can I do a between query to check if `month = '2010-01-01'` is between starting and ending

**Edit**

I have deals in de Deals table. I want to know if there is a deal in January 2010(2010-01-01), February 2010(2010-02-01), etc

Like this

```
SELECT * FROM deals WHERE '2010-01-01' BETWEEN starting AND ending
```

Comment: Checking if a month is between a particular start/end doesn't require a query. Do you actually mean you want to find the `Dates` instance(s) where `month` is between starting and ending?

Comment: I edited the topic. I need to find deals that apply for each month of a certain year. Hope it's clear

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Deals.objects.filter(starting__gte=mydate, ending__lte=mydate)
```

Doc is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#gte)

Comment: So i don't have to use between. Thanks!

Comment: __range might be useful here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#range